# Как указать обработчику кнопки внутри ListView выйти из текущего Activity?

Tags: java, android

Есть кастомный ListView, каждый Item содержит Button.

Есть

```
BoxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    ArrayList<ItemRSD> objects;

   BoxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemRSD> products) {
      ctx = context;
      objects = products;
      lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   }
```

Я понимаю, что надо реализовать в Activity View.OnClickListener, а потом его передать в адаптер и в методе getView вешать этот слушатель (переданный в адаптер) на нужный элемент разметки, передавая position через setTag у View. Но как это должно выглядеть?
В конечном итоге, надо нажав на кнопку в одном из Item, выйти из Activity и передать в onActivityResult номер Item.

Comment: Если в лоб задачу решать, то можно в `getView()`  повесить на кнопку слушатель, в нём скастовать контекст к активити, `setResult` вызвать у оной и завершить её, вызвав `finish()`. В более красивом варианте в адаптер будет передан интерфейс, реализация которого всё это будет делать и будет вызываться в `getView()` в слушателе нажатий кнопки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Здесь](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/165685/listview-arrayadapter-setting-onclicklistener-to-items) указан очень хороший способ передачи ClickListener в адаптер. Вам необходимо создать ClickListener внутри Вашего Activity, внутри которого Вы реализуете описанное выше поведение. После Вы всего лишь передадите этот обработчик нажатий в адаптер :)